# Adding multiple geoJSON files in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, geojson

So I have two separate geoJSON files in my scripts folder, one for drawing boundary lines and one for putting markers. Each geoJSON file has different contents, for example:

```
var putMarkers = {
    type: 'Feature',
    "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-77.03, 38.90]},
    "properties": {
        "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Cherry_Blossoms_and_Washington_Monument.jpg/320px-Cherry_Blossoms_and_Washington_Monument.jpg",
    "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Washington,_D.C.",
    "marker-symbol": "star",
    "marker-color": "#ff8888",
    "marker-size": "large",
    "city": "Washington, D.C."
    }
}
```

and another one:

```
var states = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","id":"01","properties":{"name":"Alabama"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-87.359296,35.00118],[-85.606675,34.984749],[-85.431413,34.124869],[-85.184951,32.859696],[-85.069935,32.580372],[-84.960397,32.421541],[-85.004212,32.322956],[-84.889196,32.262709],[-85.058981,32.13674],[-85.053504,32.01077],[-85.141136,31.840985],[-85.042551,31.539753],[-85.113751,31.27686],[-85.004212,31.003013],[-85.497137,30.997536],[-87.600282,30.997536],[-87.633143,30.86609],[-87.408589,30.674397],[-87.446927,30.510088],[-87.37025,30.427934],[-87.518128,30.280057],[-87.655051,30.247195],[-87.90699,30.411504],[-87.934375,30.657966],[-88.011052,30.685351],[-88.10416,30.499135],[-88.137022,30.318396],[-88.394438,30.367688],[-88.471115,31.895754],[-88.241084,33.796253],[-88.098683,34.891641],[-88.202745,34.995703],[-87.359296,35.00118]]]}}}
```

putting one geoJSON in this format works,

```
var geoJson = L.mapbox.featureLayer(states).addTo(map);
```

but how do you add another geoJSON?

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many featurelayers as you want:

```
var stateCollection = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [...]};
var countyCollection = {"type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [...]};

var stateLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(stateCollection).addTo(map);
var countyLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(countyCollection).addTo(map);
```

Example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/lY08pEq3O9UYZrCFrbo8?p=preview
(add your own access token to test)

Comment: thanks though it doesn't work, but kinda enlightened me

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, added an example which works like a charm.